# Match a value within range, copy and insert data into other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 50 sheets with data and 1 master sheet that contains columns of updated data which could match any one of 50 sheets.

If a value in range B2:Z2 (MasterSheet) matches a value in B2:H2 in one of the sheets within a workbook, then copy all the data below its matching cell from (MasterSheet) and insert into the sheet that contains the matching value, below the matching cell, without overwriting data.

Mastersheet with updated data

[image: Mastersheet with updated data]

Matches values in Sheet10, inserts the data from MasterSheet without overwriting existing ones (text in purple)

[image: Matches values in Sheet10, inserts the data from MasterSheet without overwriting existing ones(text in purple)]

I tried the following code but I received errors.

```
Sub InsertUpdatedMeasurement()
  Dim sRange As Range, Rng As Range, WS As Worksheet, FindString As String
  FindString = Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("B2:Z2").Value

  For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets        
    LastRow = Sheets("MasterSheet").Range(Rows.Count,"B2:Z2").End(xlUp).Row.Offset(,1)

    If WS.Name <> "MasterSheet" Then
      WS.Activate

      LastRow2 = ActiveSheet.Range(Range.Count "B2:Z2").End(xlUp).Row.Offset(,1)
      Set sRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:Z2" & LastRow2)

      With sRange
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _ 
          After:=.Cells(1), _
          LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
          LookAt:=xlWhole, _ 
          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _ 
          MatchCase:=False)         

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
          Rng.Copy       
          ActiveSheet.Rows(Rng).Selection.Insert.Shift:=xlDown     
          Application.CutCopyMode = False
          LastRow1 = LastRow1 + 1        
        End If
      End With
    End If       
  Next Ws

  Sheets("MasterSheet").Activate
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

Comment: _"I've received errors"_: what kind of errors? which line is throwing them?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give a good answer without rewriting the whole code.  Hopefully, this will get you past your errors.

Replace these line

> LastRow2 = ActiveSheet.Range(Range.Count "B2:Z2").End(xlUp).Row.Offset(,1)
>
> Set sRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:Z2" & LastRow2)

With this line

> Set sRange = Range("B2:Z2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1)

It appears the you are trying to duplicate `Rng`.

```
Rng.Copy
ActiveSheet.Rows(Rng).Selection.Insert.Shift:=xlDown

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

This will shift the range down

> Rng.Insert.Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Comment: Thanks so much Thomas!  I am very sorry for the late feedback.  And you were right, it had to be rewritten. Thanks again.